# How To use SQL Query For Printing Sql Table's Colum Names In Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, sql

I am Using This Code In JOomla Component.

```
$db2 =& JFactory::getDBO();
 $query3="SELECT * FROM sys.columns where object_id = object_id('#__demo')";
  $db2->setQuery($query3);
  $col=$db2->loadObjectList();
  echo " $col";
```

Using my sql Server

Answer (score 0):

try this:TThis is in SQL Server)

```
USE tempDB

SELECT * FROM sys.columns where object_id = object_id('#__demo')
```

Since you are using the temp table,it will be created in tempDB.So you have to get its column from tempDB

Im Printing The Query Using The  Following Code.

```
$db2->setQuery($query3);  
$col=$db2->loadObjectList();   
echo "$col";
```

--Code Corrected

```
$db2 =& JFactory::getDBO();
 $query3="use tempDB go SELECT * FROM sys.columns where object_id = object_id('#__demo')";
  $db2->setQuery($query3);
  $col=$db2->loadObjectList();
  echo " $col";
```

Comment: first tell me which DB are you using sql server mysql or anytrhing else?

Comment: Yes Im Using Sql server Mysql.

Comment: sql server and mysql are different dbs

Comment: Not Working For My joomla Component

Comment: Its Not Giving Any Error; But Not Giving any Output Also.

Comment: if you run this query in query window os sql server it will run properly just check that.